# How to perform CPU mining on bitcoin TESTNET on Linux?

Tags: bitcoind, mining-profitability, lightning-network, miner-configuration, testnet

I need approximately 100 Bitcoin Testnet to run an experiment on the lightning network.

Any suggestion on how to run CPU mining? Should I use cgminer?
Make any sense to perform solo mining on testnet?

Currently I am running a full testnet node with bitcoind on a linux environment.

Comment: Maybe you can find a faucet? Here is an older but probably still appropriate answer: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29791/how-can-i-do-cpu-mining-on-testnet

Comment: You will have to wait until the difficulty is reset to 1, and even then, you might not be able to win a block with the flood of other blocks coming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to mine Testnet BTC with CPU (even with the basic generatetoaddress command), because testnet difficulty drops significantly when there are no blocks on the network for 20 minutes:

```
bitcoin-cli generatetoaddress nblocks "address" ( maxtries )
```

If you want to continuously mine on Linux, create a bash loop:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    bitcoin-cli generatetoaddress 1 "2N5fJkfCv4cF6vsa5QQJnsazBKWNXynn9zp" 10000000
done
```

Your luck will depend on other miners activity, for example I was able to mine [6 blocks](https://mempool.space/testnet/address/2N5fJkfCv4cF6vsa5QQJnsazBKWNXynn9zp) in 2.5 months.

Comment: 'generate' methods are only effective on Regtest, where you can create blocks at will.
Testnet works like Mainnet (although with lower difficulty), so you need proper mining equipment to generate a block.

Comment: You can mine with this command, like I did, check my testnet BTC address: https://blockstream.info/testnet/address/2N5fJkfCv4cF6vsa5QQJnsazBKWNXynn9zp
This is possible because the difficulty drops to 1 on testnet if there is no new block after 20 minutes.